# UTC to EST Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, date-conversion

While converting this date (only date, no time required) `2018-03-31T00:00:00.000Z` to EST, I keep getting `2018-03-30`.

What am I doing wrong with Moment.js? Can't this be converted to EST with `2018-03-31`?

Answer (score 3):

EST is 4 hours behind UTC, so midnight (00:00:00) on the 31st in UTC is 8pm (20:00:00) on the *30th* in EST.

Moment.js is doing exactly as it should.